# Is there any driver for USB 3.0 in GA-B75M-D3V?

Tags: 12.04, usb, transfer

I got a new computer last week (with motherboard GA-B75M-D3V). On it's motherboard, there is a USB 3.0 port. I tried to use it for transfer a big data to my harddisk by Ubuntu 12.04. But the speed isn't as speed as i use on my laptop (reach 92.2 MBps on my laptop, but on my new computer it is only 21.2 MBps - like ordinary usb transfer). I tried to look on additional driver, but only graphic driver shown there.

Is Ubuntu 12.04 support USB 3.0 natively? If not, Is there any driver for USB 3.0 on my motherboard?

Comment: Linux supports USB 3.0 as of September 2009 (release of the 2.6.31 kernel). Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala was the first version of Ubuntu to support USB 3.0. And no... installing drivers is a Windows mentality ;) Linux supports hardware with generic drivers.

Comment: Does it work if you blacklist `uas` (`/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`)?

Comment: @Rinzwind How do i blacklist `uas` on `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` in a terminal and

then go to the bottom of the file and type in:

```
blacklist uas
```